# Use Blazor Wasm but not a SPA just within normal Razor MVC Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, blazor, webassembly

I looked around for quite a while but found no satisfying result.
I want to use normal Razor Pages within .Net Core MVC. I used Angular before to enrich my Views for UI functionality. I do not need a SPA, I just want to use C# code for UI modification. Can I use Blazor in any way just to use C# code for client side interactions instead of Javascript/Angular (etc.) and still render most of my views on the server just like normal MVC?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!

It is a well-documented scenario. [Prerender and integrate ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#render-components-in-a-page-or-view-with-a-css-selector)

Basicaly you want to do something like that:

```
@using BlazorHosted.Client.Pages

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />

@section Scripts {
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the component scenario. But I was hoping to use "onclick","if this use that class" etc. anywhere in my razor view, without creating components. Is that possible in any way?

Comment: I'm unaware of that but it sounds like the whole point behind Blazor. A razor view where you can use c# logic client-side is a blazor (razor) component. Is ".NET Core MVC" a requirement? Have you considered using Blazor-Server?

Comment: Seems like I will go Blazor Server direction, although I am not very comfortable with a constant SignalR connection behind the scene. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is nothing to worry about. I use Blazor in production since net core 3.1 and it is very reliable, not speaking about the massive productivity boost you will get. Good luck!